# App approved, but crashes

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have made a Windows Phone app (for WP7.1) that uses BackgroundAudio for streaming, nothing too complicated. It was approved and made available for download in the store. However it no longer works, i.e. the app worked in debug+release when run from VS2012, and I assume the .xap I uploaded worked since microsoft approved it (they rejected it once and I was able to reproduce and fix the bugs they reported).

When downloaded the app simply bails on load on WP8 (lumia 820) i.e. flips back to the tiles immediately.

On WP7 (lumia 800) but the playbutton ignores input, however it downloads and displays the playlist, so some kind of functionality+network connection works.

I have tried the basics: installing using the application-deployment tool (app working), running the  "Store Test Kit" which reports some slowdowns in the UI animations, but nothing serious (I hope).

Any ideas how to reproduce ".xap approved and downloaded from store but not working" or getting debug info from the phone without VS? Or any other things i can try out?

Comment: I had a similar thing happening to me. I submitted an app, but overlooked one (nasty) bug. The app was unable to start, it just crashed. I overlooked this, because it only happened when the app was reinstalled, not updated.
Anyways, the thing went through certification, I downloaded it to test and voila: It crashed. So I quickly unpublished it and prevented it going too public.
I can't understand, why this app could be certified in the first place. I mean don't the run it? I mean the app quit with a nullexception on startup. No chance they missed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your app crashes it will be logged and reported on your Windows Phone Dev Center Account. Just go in there and export the details to excel. Get the stack trace and put it in here. Maybe we can help.

[image: Click on Export Stack Traces]

[image: It will save an excel file like this]

Comment: Very useful info, is there anyway to do that without user being able to download the app? I.e. if I publish the app, download it to my testphones, and then "hide app in store" I should be able to test and get crashreports without bad reviews. Have anyone tried this?

Comment: Yes that should still work. However, it boggles my mind why you are having this issue. I have published 25+ apps across 7.1 7.8 and 8. I have NEVER seen this issue. Not to say it isn't possible but there might be other underlying issues. Are you sure you can't duplicate it before publishing? What is the app?

Comment: If you want help debuging let me know. I can do a code review if you would like. You can send me a private message through my site www.AnthonyRussell.info make sure to leave contact info and Ill get back to you when I am free.

Comment: It is a simple streaming app, play/stop-button and a page with a playlist, everything gotten via HTTP. It was rejected the first time,  the submitted and approved version have some extra handling of network disconnects and inputs to the UniversalVolumeControl.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the crahsreports and maybe see if I can generate and upload some more errors, I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing i can tell you is the opening page has some exceptions and that too it doesn't go well with some phones. Seriously there are concerns when a wp7 app is ported on wp8 device and vice-verse. To the extent of my knowledge there might be some binding issues. make sure you got the binding class to be public. And just as @AMR mentioned go the dev center and export the stacktrace. Try resolving them. Moreover if an app get certifies, it doesn't mean it is completely error free. The tests are limited to very coomon errors only.