# Windows phone: download xap before publish, possible?

Tags: windows-phone

Is there any way to download an approved .xap before publishing or if it is hidden?

I want to be able to test the .xap before users get to download it, but the only way to download it is from the store when it is published and not hidden. Or?

I had a problem with an approved app that crashed when downloaded and installed,

[App approved, but crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309748/app-approved-but-crashes)

so it would be nice to test and get crashreports on the exact .xap that users get to download later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. When you are publishing the app you can choose if it is a beta test, to hide it from the store or to publish it right away. You can get it approved then use the download link provided.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add a bit more detail to the above answer.

Publish as a beta and the app doesn't go through approval: it gets 'published' almost instantly (within a couple of hours) and the link will work for anyone you've registered as a beta tester (by including their email address in the list of beta testers). I'm not sure if you need to add yourself as a beta tester to get the app, but it won't hurt to add your own email address anyway.

You can also publish the app but make it hidden. This will go through the normal (~one week) approval/testing process, and then be published as usual, but hidden in the store. The app won't appear in searches, but can be downloaded by anyone who knows the link (e.g. you).

And apparently, a beta app can't be 'promoted' to a full app - you will have to resubmit as a non-beta app once you're satisfied.